# .Net Project Build Issues

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a project (1 of 41) that will not load in Visual Studio 2012.  I have inherited the solution and am attempting to get the environment spun up.  There was an error stating that SQLServer.targets could not be found so I copied the file from my 3.5 folder to the 4.0 folder.  Now, I am receiving the following error when attempting to reload the project:

```
error  : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.DatabaseFileNode' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.Internal.FolderNode'.
```

Any thoughts?  I feel like I am spinning my wheels at this point.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue converting a class project that contained CLR stored procs for SQL Server. The VS 2012 conversion attempted to convert this to a sqlproj, but failed. Rather than try to track down the source of the problem, I removed the project from the solution, added a SQL Server Database Project, then dropped my code files into that new project.